# Protocol conversion: 10GBASE-KR to 10GBASE-R

Tags: 10gbethernet, sfp

I wanted to get some insight if anyone is aware of transceivers or translation devices that would be able to convert 10GBASE-KR to 10GBASE-R. The intent is to support a 10GBASE-KR interface from a VPX backplane out to an SFP+ cage, but the processor on other end of the fiber only allows for 10GBASE-R. Any thoughts?

Comment: maybe it's helpful for You reading suitable parts of a multi-rate transceiver manual [e.g. TLK10031 Single-Channel XAUI/10GBASE-KR Transceiver (~2.1MB, pdf)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlk10031.pdf?ts=1698985007073&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F#page=134), but it seems, there's no protocol conversion necessary between 10GBASE-KR and 10GBASE-R and if there are physical SFP+ connectors on every side it might be enough to just connect both sides (and adjust configuration)

Comment: another option: multi-speed transceiver manual [e.g. Marvell® 88X2222 (~10.6MB, pdf)](https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/phys-transceivers/marvell-phys-transceivers-alaska-x-88x2222-datasheet.pdf#page=4)

Comment: Intel explains the IP implementation for Arria® Fpga on [10GBASE-R and 10GBASE-KR](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683573/current/10gbase-r-and-10gbase-kr.html) and [configuration](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683573/current/10gbase-r-and-10gbase-kr-transceiver.html) and there are adapters from VPX to (4x) SFP+ connectors available (e.g. Intel® Ethernet Controller XL710, page 9(1871), ~15MB, pdf)